# XML find and delete all text in doc not within a specified tag

Tags: regex, xml

I have an XML doc which is massive - a short example is below to illustrate formatting. What I want to do is find all the text in the doc which is not within a  tag and delete it - so I am left with just a list of the  data...

So here is the original:

```
51.639973121-2.161205923
112.0
<time>2017-02-19T11:26:45Z</time>

51.639902964-2.161258059
111.6
<time>2017-02-19T11:26:46Z</time>

51.639834484-2.161310529
111.6
<time>2017-02-19T11:26:47Z</time>

51.639765501-2.161366101
111.6
<time>2017-02-19T11:26:48Z</time>

51.639697859-2.161426451
111.8
<time>2017-02-19T11:26:49Z</time>
```

And once formatted - it will become:

```
<time>2017-02-19T11:26:45Z</time>
<time>2017-02-19T11:26:46Z</time>
<time>2017-02-19T11:26:47Z</time>
<time>2017-02-19T11:26:48Z</time>
<time>2017-02-19T11:26:49Z</time>
```

How is this possible???

Comment: Regex isn't the way to parse xml, If you do it in PHP and if your file is big, you can use the XMLReader class (that doesn't need to load the whole file at once, and doesn't need to build a DOM tree).

Comment: Its an offline file - can be opened / edited with anything to be honest...

Comment: must be a way to do it with regex? ^[#;].* is near the expression I need I think?

Comment: With a command line: `xmllint --xpath //time file.xml | sed 's/></>\n</g'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following expression will select all text but time tags:

```
^(?!<time>[^<]+<\/time>).*\R
```

It works only if the tags are on a new line, like in you example input.

[See the demo](https://regex101.com/r/yYUZHb/2)

Comment: Thanks - works in your demo yes - not in the Dreamweaver find tool though... how can I use Regex to make this work?

Comment: Also want a delete command once it has found all the none <time> tag content

Comment: Thanks! ;) Works very well

Comment: @dubbs I've updated my post, see the new link for result at regex101.com. You're welcome. :)

Comment: Thanks @Niitaku - Do you have any ideas on a solution for this one also? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42354609/replace-all-time-tags-in-one-doc-with-those-from-another

Comment: any ideas on a solution for this related question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42354609/replace-all-time-tags-in-one-doc-with-those-from-another